# PHP refusing to accept cookies

Tags: php, html, firefox

When I develop web page Faced a problem which happen when use session

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
    if ($type == 'admin') {
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $User;
                $_SESSION['UserType'] = 'admin';
                header('Location: Main.php');
            } else if ($type == 'manager' && $PID != "") {
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $User;
                $_SESSION['UserType'] = 'manager';
                $_SESSION['PID'] = $PID;
                header('Location: MainPage.php');
            }
?>
```

this Error in all my cases:

"**Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

**This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.**"

[image: this Error in all my cases]

Comment: There are no cookies in your code. It's just that your code is making a redirection on same page and never stops. check all of your sesisons and if else statements , be sure nothing is invalid

Comment: I think in other words - You've god yourself an endless redirecting loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script looks like that youre redirecting in a circle. Main.php-> main.php -> main.php and so on. Check your script for such a mistake

Comment: Who downvoted this? It makes perfect sense. Upvote from me. :-)